# Why i cant see the values of my snapshot.value from firebase database in a Text widget in flutter?

Tags: database, flutter, firebase, dictionary, object

i have the next code:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref();
  late DatabaseReference databaseReference;
  final data = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref();
  var medsValues;

_activateListeners() {
    data.get().then((snapshot) {
      var medsDescription = snapshot.value;
      setState(() {
        medsValues = medsDescription;
      });
    });
  }    

ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: medsValues.length,
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                            return ListTile(
                              leading: Icon(Icons.medication),
                              title: medsValues[index].forEach((key, value) {
                                key == "username" ? Text(value.toString()) : null;
                              }),
                            );
                          },
                        )
```

But if I change the Text() widget with a print() and print the value in console without the .toString(), this shows correctly, Can you help me please?

thanks for your help in advance

this is my DB in firebase Database:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

it's just a guess, but I believe you're missing adding typing to your variables, try declaring

```
Object medsValues;  
Object medsDescription = snapshot.value
```

instead of

```
var medsValues;
var medsDescription = snapshot.value
```

Or try to create a class that represents your object and override the toString or access the attribute you want to display in Text()

Comment: Thank you for your response, I'm a doctor (I do clinical research) I do this just for fun, and I'm learning, could you be more specífic please. Thank you in advance

Comment: of course, when the variable is declared only with the reserve word "var" it receives the type dynamic, this type allows it to be any value, even null values, when the type is specified in the way I suggested, as Object or as some class , makes the variable of a more specific type, not being allowed null values, unless specified with the character "?", for example: 

Object? medsDescription = snapshot.value

obs.: sorry for any spelling mistakes, I'm not fluent

Comment: If this is the correct answer to your question, I can edit the answer by adding the explanation given above

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand your question completely, also your code is not clean enough so please take a look at firebase documentations on how to retrieve snapshots from database. you should also await for your get() method to complete,
for that consider using a StreamBuilder or FutureBuilder to get your snapshot(s) from the database.

```
_activateListeners() async{
await data.get().then((snapshot) {
  var medsDescription = snapshot.value;
  setState(() {
    medsValues = medsDescription;
  });
});
```

}

Comment: I think I resolve this with a if null... But I don't know why if I print the value in console the value shows correctly but if I put the value in a text() widget it does not show in the app